# Button-sized icons in operator?

Tags: operator

I essentially want to make buttons with an image inside, similar to how template_icon_view works, but with the functionality of an operator button.

I haven't found any way to resize icons, or to change the function of a template_icon_view to act as a button instead of opening a preview menu. What can I do to achieve this?

Comment: I have basically the same question. Did you figure it out?